# Draw a route on google map on click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What I am trying to do is on click google maps, place a marker, and draw a route between these markers. This works but the problem I'm facing is as follows: (please view the images of map)

(1) When I click three times on google map, the route is drawn perfectly. (meaning first I click `A` then `B` and then `C` location)

[image]

(2) Then if I click a forth time on google map, the location must be `D` but the map looks as follows:

Here the `B` location is replaced or hidden and in place of `B`, `C` is displayed and same...
[image]

(3) If I click a fifth time on google map, the location should be `E`, but the map looks like:

[image]

In short, if I click five times on google map, the route should be 'A,B,C,D,E'. Instead it is displayed as 'A,E,F,G,H'.

The full code is as follows:

```
<script>
    var waypts=[];
    var ways=[];
    function initialize() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var mapOptions = {
                            zoom: 11,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.0171240, 72.5330533),
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                         };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
            placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
            var input=e.latLng;
            var lat = parseFloat(input.lat());
            var lng = parseFloat(input.lng());
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var add=results[1].formatted_address;
                    waypts.push({
                        location:add,
                        stopover:true
                    });
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(waypts));
                    if(waypts.length>2) {
                        for ( var i = 1; i <= waypts.length - 2 ; i++) {
                            ways.push({
                                location:waypts[i].location,
                                stopover:true
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    makeroute(waypts);
                }
            });
        });

        <!--  **************    for route between markers   *******************  -->
        function makeroute(waypts){
            var directionsDisplay;
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                suppressMarkers: false, //false it if you want a marker from the direction service
                polylineOptions: {
                    strokeColor: 'green', //"black",
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 3
                }
            });

            var start = waypts[0].location;//"Bopal, Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India";
            var end = waypts[waypts.length-1].location;//"Nikol, Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India";

            if(waypts.length>1) {
                var request = {
                                 origin:start,
                                 destination:end,
                                 waypoints:ways,
                                 travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                               };
                directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    }
                });

                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
            }
        }
    }

    function placeMarker(position, map) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            //map: map
        });
        // map.panTo(position);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

**LATER UPDATE**

I use `directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('a'));` for the full route information.

It display when ever I click on google map, the routes is repeat. Meaning on the first click `A`, on second click `A to B`, on third `A to B to C` not `B to C` etc. It also display that some points merged. For example `B and C` have same location and on the map `C` is only displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear out the waypoints array ("ways") each time you add a new point. Each time you add a point, the start point stays the same but the old end point needs to be added to the waypoints array, and the new point is the end point.  Currently you never clear out the "ways" array. Changing this:

```
  if(waypts.length>2) {
    for ( var i = 1; i <= waypts.length - 2 ; i++) {
       ways.push({
         location:waypts[i].location,
         stopover:true
       });
    }
  }
  makeroute(waypts);
```

To this:

```
  if(waypts.length>2) {
    ways = [];
    for ( var i = 1; i <= waypts.length - 2 ; i++) {
       ways.push({
         location:waypts[i].location,
         stopover:true
       });
    }
  }
  makeroute(waypts);
```

Works for me.